# How can i test a function that return a promise or reject - Jasmine and Karma

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, jasmine2.0

I need to cover 100% of the tests of a function, it returns a `return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject)` this is the full function.

```
saveData(): Promise < boolean > {
    return new Promise < boolean > ((resolve, reject) => {
        this.legaloneService.saveFinancialData(this.financialModel).subscribe(
            m => {
                if (!m.Success) {
                    const mapFiels: {
                        [id: string]: string
                    } = {};
                    mapFiels['accountName'] = 'Nome da conta';
                    mapFiels['bankId'] = 'Banco';
                    mapFiels['agency'] = 'Agência';
                    mapFiels['accountNumber'] = 'Conta';
                    this.functionsService.displayErrorFromAPII(m, mapFiels);
                }
                resolve(m.Success);
            },
            error => {
                const msg = 'Ocorreu uma falha ao salvar os dados financeiros';
                this.functionsService.cathError(error, msg);
                reject(msg);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

A few days ago I got help from someone here, and I am trying to solve this issue using his tips, my test is as follows:

```
it('testing resolve a promise', fakeAsync(() => {

    spyOn(component, 'saveData').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
    spyOn(funcService, 'displayErrorFromAPII').and.stub();

    component.saveData()
        .then(r => {
            console.log(r);
            expect(funcService.displayErrorFromAPII).toHaveBeenCalled();
            flush(200);
        })
        .catch(e => fail(e));

    expect(component.saveData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

and this is my current coverage:

[My current coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2wH3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, you mocks the method `saveData` under test, the real implementation will not be involved and code coverage will not improve. Therefore you should remove the following statement from your test.

```
spyOn(component, 'saveData').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
```

You should mock the method `legaloneService.saveFinancialData` instead since this is a unit test. Since `saveData` is returning a `Promise`, you can use the `done` callback function.

To have full code coverage, you need the following two tests.

```
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
...

it('#saveData should display error when financial data cannot be saved', (done) => {    
    const saveFinancialDataResult = ?; // replace ? with expected !Success result    
    spyOn(legaloneService, 'saveFinancialData').and.returnValue(of(saveFinancialDataResult));
    spyOn(funcService, 'displayErrorFromAPII').and.stub();

    component.saveData()
        .then(r => {
            expect(funcService.displayErrorFromAPII).toHaveBeenCalled();    
            done();        
        })
        .catch(e => fail(e));
});

it('#saveData should catch error when error occurs', (done) => {    
    spyOn(legaloneService, 'saveFinancialData').and.returnValue(throwError('server error'));
    spyOn(funcService, 'cathError').and.stub();

    component.saveData()
        .then(r => fail('should have been rejected'))
        .catch(e => {
            expect(functionsService.cathError).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
});
```

> Please consult https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync and https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async for detailed information about different testing strategies with Angular and Jasmine.